# Is there a way to pass state to pages in Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, routes, state, gatsby

Since Gatsby effectively hides the router, you can't pass props to each page in the way you would with BrowserRouter in Create-React-App. Is there a way to do this in Gatsby? I assume I need to do it somehow in Gatsby-browser.js. I basically want to maintain a state called Step, that is accessible by all pages. Would I have to use Context for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass state into a page with `Link` ([docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/built-in-components/gatsby-link/#pass-state-as-props-to-the-linked-page)), but be mindful of pages being built without state (i.e. statically).

```
<Link
  to={`/photos/`}
  state={{ tag }}
>
  See more {tag}
</Link>
```

```
const PhotosPage = ({ location: { state } }) => 
  <div>{state?.tag ? `${tag} photos` : "All photos"}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The native (and easiest) way is using [React context](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/blog/2019-01-31-using-react-context-api-with-gatsby/) but you have multiple ways of sharing a global state in Gatsby:

- Using global wrappers within the `wrapRootElement` exposed API:

  ```
  import React from "react"
  import { ThemeProvider } from "./src/context/ThemeContext"

  export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
     <ThemeProvider>{element}</ThemeProvider>
  )
  ```

  If you follow this approach, you'll need to use `wrapRootElement` in both `gatsby-browser.js` as well `gatsby-ssr.js` since it's a [shared API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement).

Keep in mind that Gatsby's router extends from `@reach/router` (from React).

In that way, you'll keep your `step` state across the application.